# 左右 2 列 markdown 形式のdiffが異常に長いことがある

Tags: バグ, 仕様, 差分表示

確認手順:

1. https://ja.stackoverflow.com/posts/4931/revisions#spacer-023ef391-b3e4-47c8-bb6b-2524206a71db を開く
2. リビジョン 2 の詳細を開く
3. 左右 2 列 markdown 形式にする

スクリーンショット:

[image: 長い]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The diff looks to be working as intended in this case. Check out the very first revision of that post: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fbf2003f-7a5d-48d5-8f5f-c4142356b8f8/view-source.

It includes a whole bunch of blank lines, which were removed by [the suggested edit](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2441) that formatted the code. The other diff views don't show them because they're based on an HTML diff engine which can't really show removed blank lines well. The raw markdown comparison, however, is more explicit.

---

質問にある投稿では差分表示は意図通り動いているようです。問題の投稿の初版を見てみてください: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/fbf2003f-7a5d-48d5-8f5f-c4142356b8f8/view-source.

初版では空行が大量にあり、その後[編集](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2441)によって削除されています。他の差分表示モードではこの空行が表示されないのは、HTMLベースの差分表示エンジンを使っているためです。HTMLベースの差分表示では削除された空行はうまく表示できません。一方、Markdown同士の比較ではそれがそのまま表示されます。